# ng-class directive call executed twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Simple html:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
 <tr data-ng-repeat="customer in customers" data-ng-class="customerSelectedClass(customer)">
  <td>
    <a href="" data-ng-click="selectCustomer(customer)">{{customer.Name}}</a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

In my controller - two functions to select customer and return proper class to highlight a table row:

```
$scope.customerSelectedClass = function (customer) {
            if (customer == $scope.selectedCustomer) {
                console.log('returing info for ' + customer.Name);
                return "info";
            }
            return "";
        };

        $scope.selectCustomer = function (customer) {
            console.log('selecting ' + customer.Name);
            $scope.selectedCustomer = customer;
        }
```

I noticed that when I click on a customer link, customerSelectedClass function executes twice. selectCustomer function on ng-click directive executes once, as it should. Angular is only included once on the page. I wonder if this is a bug in Angular or something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expression evaluated 2 times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078231/expression-evaluated-2-times)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the scenes, angular is setting up a `$watch` on the function that is resolving the class name.  Because angular uses [dirty checking](http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/17/angular_is_slow/) to see if there has been a change, this method will be called twice during the `$digest` cycle.  This is ok.

I would suggest that you don't add this code the the controller though, because if you are managing many css classes, you could be adding a lot of unnecessary code.  Try something like this instead:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
 <tr data-ng-repeat="customer in customers" data-ng-class="{'info': customer == selectedCustomer}">
  <td>
    <a href="" data-ng-click="selectCustomer(customer)">{{customer.Name}}</a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Then, there is no need for a controller function `customerSelectedClass`.  This will only add the `info` class if the right-hand side of the `:` resolves to true.  And there is no problem resolving the correct customer in the `ng-repeat`.

Hope this helps.