# angularjs calling Filter twice with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am new to `angularjs` and trying to learn concept of filters.But in my case `angularjs` is calling the filter twice.I was expecting filter to run only once but its running twice. Cant understand why this is happening..

here is my **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y3r0YOPFaQM4G5PhzMDj)**...

Comment: What do you expect your output to be? I don't understand the question.

Comment: @AmalAntony: i am just checking out filters while doing so i am getting the issue that filter is getting twice.

Comment: The filter is getting called twice because there are 2 elements in your model (i.e `$scope.actors`). The filter is called once for each element. Does that clarify your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expression evaluated 2 times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078231/expression-evaluated-2-times)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If i don't take your question wrong, this is the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676901/is-this-normal-for-angularjs-filtering)**

> **Angularjs** uses a 'dirty-check' approach, so it need to call all the filters to see if exists any change. After this it detect that have a change on one variable(the one that you typed) and then it execute all filters again to detect if has other changes.
>
> To be more clear understanding, [stackoverflow this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs) will explain in more detail by expert in angularjs

[Here is another plunker same calling filter twice](http://plnkr.co/edit/nuSlCRB6Y7QbuLC67uzW)

> The **first** call is from the watchers that are detecting the change. Because there is one then they need to be called again to see if is there news changes because a watcher can make changes.