# Filter `module` triggers two time.. is it nature of freamwork

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angular, I created a custome filter. works fine. But it seems that called by 2 times...

is it quite nature of `Angularjs` with some good reasons or my way of works is wrong here?

Any one explain / detail me in this regard.

here is my code :

```js
angular.module('sportsStore', ["customFilters"]);

angular.module('sportsStore')
 .controller('sportsStoreCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.data = {
   products : [
    { name: "Product #1", description: "A product", category: "Category #1", price: 100 },
    { name: "Product #2", description: "A product", category: "Category #1", price: 110 },
    { name: "Product #3", description: "A product", category: "Category #2", price: 210 },
    { name: "Product #4", description: "A product", category: "Category #3", price: 202 }
   ]
  }
 }]);

angular.module("customFilters", [])
.filter('unique', function () {
 return function (data, propertyName) {
  console.log(data, propertyName); //consoles 2 times - why?
  if(angular.isArray(data) && angular.isString(propertyName)) {

   var results = [];
   var keys = {};

   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var val = data[i][propertyName]
    if(angular.isUndefined(keys[val])) {
     keys[val] = true;
     results.push(val);
    }
   }

   return results;

  } else {
   return data;
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sportsStore">
    <div ng-controller="sportsStoreCtrl">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
    <a ng-click="selectCategory()"
    class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">Home</a>
    <a ng-repeat="item in data.products | orderBy:'category' | unique:'category'"
    ng-click="selectCategory(item)" class=" btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">
    {{item}}
   </a>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798566/angularjs-calling-filter-twice-with-ng-repeat

Comment: wait for angular 2.0 xD