# AngularJS custom filter being called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a custom filter using AngularJS that prints out the fruits that start with a p. As far as I can tell, I've implemented the custom filter correctly.

I'm printing out a message every time the filter is called but I'm curious to why my filter is being called twice.

Looking at similar problems on stackoverflow I found one person who had a similar issue however the problem wasn't answered and was a little different.

JSFiddle Solution
http://jsfiddle.net/ddemott/U3pVM/22606/

HTML Code

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl" ng-app="sampleApp">
    <div class="showDiffTags" ng-repeat="val in values | myFilter:'p'">{{val.name}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

AngularJS Code

```
angular.module('sampleApp', []).filter('myFilter', function() {

  return function(items, firstLetter) {
    var groups = [];
    console.log("called function");
    console.log(items.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i].name.substring(0, 1) == firstLetter) {
    groups.push(items[i]);
      }
    }
    return groups;
  }
}).controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.values = [{
    name: 'apple'
  }, {
    name: 'banana'
  }, {
    name: 'orange'
  }, {
    name: 'avocado'
  }, {
    name: 'pineapple'
  }, {
    name: 'peach'
  }, {
    name: 'plum'
  }, {
    name: 'grapes'
  }, {
    name: 'mango'
  }, {
    name: 'papaya'
  }, ];
});
```

Comment: I believe this may be the same question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798566/angularjs-calling-filter-twice-with-ng-repeat

Comment: I see.  I wasn't sure of this so I didn't believe this was my answer however now that I know it is the natural cycle of how angularjs works,  I can see how it would be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct behaviour and it's strongly coupled with how `$digest` cycle works

Every time model changes the `$digest` is run at least twice:

1. After model changes it runs the watchers and updates the models
2. To check if the first `$digest` made changes to model, if so another digest is called up to max ten iterations then angular throw errors.

There is nothing to worry unless you have a lot of functions in templates and unstable models (changing often)

I've updated your fiddle with simple button that updates model on scope

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/22610/

```
<button ng-click="numModel = numModel + 1">
  update model {{numModel}}
</button>
```

You will see that every time you click the button filter runs twice

Comment: But it must have something changed to trigger the digest loop.If we remove the button and in filter, we return the original items then it still run twice.

Comment: But it does change, isn't it? You return subset with filter, so you change model

Comment: I said that if we return the original items in filter in my previous comment. You can see plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UANI9oK4CgM8w99kpmAM?p=preview)

Comment: Sure but after initialising model `$digest` runs too

Comment: You mean that when model initializing, it call $digest loop and after it's done, it call $digest one more time ?

Comment: No i mean you initialize model and that makes the `digest` run twice - classical two runs after change and to check if the first digest changed something